# Travis skipping S3 deployment because branch is not permitted

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci

I have a new issue with a Travis build. In brief, my `.travis.yml` file contains:

```
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: mYacc3ssKeyID
  secret_access_key:
    secure: mYacc3ssKey
  bucket: my-bucket-staging
  skip_cleanup: true
  local_dir: dist/
  acl: public_read
  on:
    branch: staging

deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: mYOtheracc3ssKeyID
  secret_access_key:
    secure: mYOtheracc3ssKey
  bucket: my-bucket
  skip_cleanup: true
  local_dir: dist/
  acl: public_read
  on:
    branch: master
```

Until August 16, this setup worked as intended (staging branch was deployed to the `my-bucket-staging` bucket, master branch was deployed to the `my-bucket` bucket, and all other branches were ignored). My `.travis.yml` file hasn't changed since July 13, but the `staging` branch stopped deploying with the message `Skipping a deployment with the s3 provider because this branch is not permitted` on August 16. My last known successful deployment was on August 15.

It's also worth noting that the master deployment still works as expected, it's just the staging branch I'm having issues with.

Since I haven't changed anything on my end (the `staging` branch is the same branch, `.travis.yml` file is the same, etc), I'm wondering if there was a change with Travis that I missed? Does anyone know why this would (seemingly) just stop working?

I reread through Travis's documentation and didn't notice anything different, but I feel like something must have changed at some point or I'm missing something terribly obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The above YAML segment defines two identical keys `deploy`, so only the last one is effective; meaning, there is no deployment provider defined with `on.branch: staging` as far as your `.travis.yml` is concerned.

If you want to define 2 deployment providers that work on different branches, you need a 2-element array under `deploy`:

```
deploy:
  - provider: s3
    access_key_id: mYacc3ssKeyID
    secret_access_key:
      secure: mYacc3ssKey
    bucket: my-bucket-staging
    skip_cleanup: true
    local_dir: dist/
    acl: public_read
    on:
      branch: staging
  - provider: s3
    access_key_id: mYOtheracc3ssKeyID
    secret_access_key:
      secure: mYOtheracc3ssKey
    bucket: my-bucket
    skip_cleanup: true
    local_dir: dist/
    acl: public_read
    on:
      branch: master
```

It is not clear to me how it could have been working before with your original configuration as indicated. I would be interested to see the working Travis CI build log.